# SQL SELECT + INNER JOIN + WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

So I have this query and can't see whats wrong

```
SELECT tasks.id,tasks.client_name,tasks.description,tasks.state, 
       tasks.planned_dates, tasks.task_for, tasks.task_type, 
       tasks.solution, tasks.created_by, users.color 
FROM public.tasks 
INNER JOIN public.users ON (tasks.created_by = users.id) 
WHERE id IN 
(
  SELECT tt.id 
  FROM (
    SELECT id, unnest(planned_dates) as dd 
    FROM tasks 
    WHERE planned_dates IS NOT NULL AND deleted = FALSE
  ) as tt 
  WHERE tt.dd BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your desired outcome, what is currently display, what is the problem? "I can't see whats wrong" is not a question. Please [read about how to improve your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what do you expect? and what is the output you get?

Comment: What's the exception being thrown? That would help immensely. Without that, the only thing I can think of is the "WHERE id IN" needs to be qualified to either users.id or tasks.id.

Comment: one thing is not correct `WHERE id = ` this is ambiguous and you need to specify `table_name.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell without seeing the error that you get. But from looking at your query it might be that

```
WHERE id IN
```

is ambiguous. Try to use `tasks.id` instead of `id` (or `users.id`, if you meant that id)